# Element not found error when trying to action on Selenium. (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I keep getting this error when im trying to access an xpath using selenium web driver:

```
find_element_by_tag_name is deprecated. 
Please use find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name) instead
warnings.warn("find_element_by_tag_name is deprecated. 
Please use find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name) instead")
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button"}
```

could someone please help.

The code i am using is as follows:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div\[1\]/section/div/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[2\]/div/div\[3\]/div/button').click()
```

It was supposed to click a send message button but didn't happen.

I've also tried

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//\*\[@id="f542a83ccd9968"\]/button').click()
```

With the same result.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.